# AzCopy is there an option to skip failed files

Tags: azcopy

I need to migrate 65TB of data to Azure Blob Storage from the Share where I have only read access. I am using AzCopy with the following command:

```
AzCopy /Source:MY_SOURCE /Dest:https://STORAGE_NAME.blob.core.windows.net/MY_CONTAINER/SOME_Name
/DestKey:MY_KEY /V:MY_FOLDER\azcopy.log  /S
```

When an error is raised with some file I can see the actual error in logs but I cannot fix any because I have only read access to the source. I would like to know if there is an **option** or some **workaround** to skip failed files, put them to logs and proceed with next ones?

Comment: Why do you need this option? Per my understanding, AzCopy by default skips failed files, and only prints the failed files in transfer summary after the whole transfer is finished.

Comment: What you are saying is the behavior I would like to achieve. With the command I use it doesn't skip the wrong files but stops running. It writes the first error it faces to a cmd line and to logs and stops transferring. If I were able to resolve the error in the source I would run the same command again and according to the created AzCopy journal it would start not from the very beginning but continue from the error file. But I cannot resolve any error in the source that is why I want AzCopy to omit wrong files, continue transferring and in the very end give a list of errors.

Comment: Could you share the detailed error? AzCopy can skip the failed files and continue, but if the failure happens on the source directory or its subdirectory, current AzCopy may not be able to continue from the error.

Comment: At same time, If preview version azcopy is acceptable in your case, please try azcopy v10 as well, which should have the behavior you expected.

Comment: @EmmaZhu-MSFT, the error was caused by wrong file naming. It ended on '.' . Failure happens on source. Seems that there is no way to skip source file errors in AzCopy 8.1.0-netcore

Comment: @FanJiachen, thank you for your advice. I tried to run it from Azure Storage Explorer which now have an option to use azcopy v10. It works as expected and skips the wrong files.